# DROOLS local variable assignment with nested members

Tags: drools

I am having trouble assigning a local variable with nested members/objects in DROOLS 6.2 and Optaplanner with two Java classes.  I am trying to determine when two facts/instances nested members have the same values.  The test case below is simple, in reality I'm trying to compare multiple nested members in a rule.

```
public class A {
  private B x;
  //public B getX(), public void setX(B b) follow ...
}

public class B {
  private int y;
  //public int getY(), public void setY(int y) follow ...
}

rule "testnestedmembers"
when  
    A(x.y : y, $x : x)
    A(x2.y == y, $x : x2) 
then 
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1000);

    Message [id=1, level=ERROR,      path=org/somebody/project/planner/solver/planScoreRules.drl, line=16, column=0
   text=[ERR 102] Line 16:49 mismatched input ':' in rule "testnestedmembers"]
    Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=org/somebody/project/planner/solver/planScoreRules.drl, line=0, column=0 text=Parser returned a null Package]
    ---
    Warning Messages:
    ---
    Info Messages:

    at    org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildKieBase(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:387)
```

I have reviewed some answers, such as:
[Drools Rule Expression : Access Nested class data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347545/drools-rule-expression-access-nested-class-data-member)

And Geoffrey De Smet's answer illustrates a conditional, but not a local assignment.
I've tried different variations, but no luck.  Thank you for any advice.

**Edit:**  I should have said **creating a binding** instead of assigning a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll point out what causes the compiler errors.

```
rule "testnestedmembers"
when  
    A(x.y : y, $x : x)     // (1)
    A(x2.y == y, $x : x2)  // (2) (3)
```

(1) A binding has the form `<variable> : <field>`, but `x.y` isn't a valid variable name.
(2) Same with `x2.y`. Also, `x2` isn't a field in A.
(3) Nothing keeps the rule engine from matching the same fact with both patterns for class A. This means that the rule will fire for each and every fact of class A, since (as you intend) A.x.y is always equal to itself.

Correct is

```
rule "testnestedmembers"
when
    $a1: A( $x1: x )
    A( this != $a1, $x2: x, $x1.getY() == $x2.getY() )
then
     ...
```

However! This rule fires twice, once with one fact bound to $a1, and once with the other (matching) one bound to $a1. One possibility is to test for the *existence* of such a pair (or cluster!):

```
rule "testnestedmembers"
when
    $a1: A( $x1: x )
    exists A( this != $a1, $x2: x, $x1.getY() == $x2.getY() )
then
     ...
```

Another option is to ensure an ordering by testing an attribute:

```
rule "testnestedmembers"
when
    $a1: A( $x1: x, $id: id )
    exists A( id > $id, $x2: x, $x1.getY() == $x2.getY() )
then
```

Now this fires for each pair of A's where the second has a greater (unique!) id.

Comment: This detailed explanation makes sense.  So the `this != $a1` ensures that the two matches represent different facts and will fire the rule for any two facts where the two `y` members are equal?

Comment: Yes - that's the idea. It forces two different objects. But it will fire twice, with the two objects reversed. You'll need another attribute to guarantee ordering. See my update.

Comment: It's nice to see both options.  Reading up in the documentation on **exists** it appears that this would be appropriate with hard constraints since **exists** implies "there is at least one.." and the rule will only fire once.

Comment: Yes -- thank you for the detailed explanation and the dialog.  I had the binding order reversed in my head and your extension to the answer regarding *exists* is an important aspect of this inquiry.

Comment: As they say, I'm new around here.  I've accepted your answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean something like this :

```
when  
  $a1 : A($y1 : x.y)
  A(this != $a1, x.y == $y1) 
then
  ...
```

As Geoffrey De Smet said :

> In DRL, `==` means equals, not same. With `$varB : b` you do something like `B varB = a.getB();`